# How to correctly plot a linear regression on a log10 scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression

I am plotting two lists of data against each other, namely `freq` and `data`. Freq stands for frequency, and data are the numeric observations for each frequency.

In the next step, I apply the ordinary linear least-squared regression between `freq` and `data`, using `stats.linregress` on the logarithmic scale. My aim is applying the linear regression inside the log-log scale, not on the normal scale.

Before doing so, I transform both `freq` and `data` into `np.log10`, since I plan to plot a straight linear regression line on the logarithmic scale, using `plt.loglog`.

**Problem:**
The problem is that the regression line, plotted in red color, is plotted far from the actual data, plotted in green color. I assume that there is a problem in combination with `plt.loglog` in my code, hence the visual distance between the green data and the red regression line. How can I fix this problem, so that the regression line plots on top of the actual data?

Here is my reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Data
freq = [0.0102539, 0.0107422, 0.0112305, 0.0117188, 0.012207, 0.0126953,
        0.0131836]
data = [4.48575,  4.11893,  3.69591,  3.34766,  3.18452,  3.23554,  3.43357]

# Plot log10 of freq vs. data
plt.loglog(freq, data, c="green")

# Linear regression
log_freq = np.log10(freq)
log_data = np.log10(data)

reg = stats.linregress(log_freq, log_data)
slope = reg[0]
intercept = reg[1]

plt.plot(freq, slope*log_freq + intercept, color="red")
```

And here is a screenshot of the code’s result:
[image]

Comment: This seems to be a math problem, not a programming problem. I guess you have to undo the logarithm which you applied for `linregress`.

Comment: Hi. Removing ```np.log10``` from the regression ```reg``` results in the opposite visual result. In this case, the red regression line is plotted far above the green data, instead of far below like now.

Comment: I hate to say it, but the answer you've accepted is rather low quality, e.g., _"Note that after the log transformation, the numbers in `log_freq` will all be negative; therefore x-axis cannot be log-scaled."_ WHY? also, in the plot you DO NOT SEE the values of original experiment, but just the logarithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

First of all, I question the necessity of log-log axes, because the ranges of the data, or at least the ranges of the data that you've shown us, are limited on both coordinates.

In the code below, I have

- computed the logarithms in base 10 of your arrays,
- used the formulas for linear regression but using the logarithms of data to obtain the equation of a straight line:
                   *y = a + b·x*
  in, so to say, the logarithmic space.

Because a straight line in log-space corresponds, in data-space, to a power law, *y = pow(10, a)·pow(x, b)*, I have plotted

- the original data, in log-log, and
- the power law, also in log-log,

obtaining a straight line in the log-log representation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10
freq = [.0102539, .0107422, .0112305, .0117188, .012207, .0126953, .0131836]
data = [4.48575, 4.11893, 3.69591, 3.34766, 3.18452, 3.23554, 3.43357]
n = len(freq)

# the following block of code is the unfolding of the formulas in
# https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPowerLaw.html

# START ##############################################    
lx, ly = [[log10(V) for V in v] for v in (freq, data)]
sum_x = sum(x for x in lx)
sum_y = sum(y for y in ly)
sum_x2 = sum(x**2 for x in lx)
sum_y2 = sum(y**2 for y in ly)
sum_xy = sum(x*y for x, y in zip(lx, ly))

# coefficients of a straight line "y = a + b x" in log-log space
b = (n*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/(n*sum_x2-sum_x**2)
a = (sum_y - b*sum_x)/n
A = pow(10, a)
# END  ##############################################    

plt.loglog(freq, data)
plt.loglog(freq, [A*pow(x, b) for x in freq])
```

Comment: Awesome code! The cool thing about your code is that one can still use ```plt.loglog```, hence there is no need to apply ```plt.xscale('symlog')``` and ```plt.yscale('symlog')``` if one wants to display both axes on the log10 scale. By ```n = len(x)``` you refer to the length of datapoints in ```freq``` or ```data```, correct? The data I work with is much longer and corresponds to a power-law. I shortened the data to reduce the code length in my initial question. I will use your code, but the single code steps are beyond my undertanding nonetheless. Could you add short # comments to the lines?

Comment: @Philipp `n = len(x)` is a mistake, benign when I tested the code in my interpreter because previously the arrays were named `x` and `y`.  You may want to use `n = len(freq)` — I have edited my answer to have _the right stuff_ in it

Comment: @Philipp Re further commenting the code… it's just unfolding, in a hopefully clear manner, the formulas reported, e.g., in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPowerLaw.html — I will add the link in the body of the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think that my mistake was that I did not state that my aim is to fit a linear least-square regression to data that approximates a power-law in log-log space. That would have made things easier right from the beginning. Anyway, thank again for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your data sets to log base 10 first, then do linear regression and plot them accordingly.

Note that after the log transformation, the numbers in`log_freq` will all be negative; therefore x-axis cannot be log-scaled.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Data
freq = np.array([0.0102539, 0.0107422, 0.0112305, 0.0117188, 0.012207, 0.0126953,
                 0.0131836])
data = np.array([4.48575, 4.11893, 3.69591, 3.34766, 3.18452, 3.23554, 3.43357])

# transform date to log base 10
log_freq = np.log10(freq)
log_data = np.log10(data)

# Plot freq vs. data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(log_freq, log_data, c="green", label='Original data (log 10 base)')

# Linear regression
reg = stats.linregress(log_freq, log_data)

# Plot fitted freq vs. data
ax.plot(log_freq, reg.slope * log_freq + reg.intercept, color="red",
        label='Fitted line on the original data (log 10 base)')

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

##### References:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html#

Comment: Well, you also removed `np.log10` which is more likely to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Hello. This works fine, but the regression line is not a straight line using this code. (Look exactly, you will see that the regression line is rather a curve.)

Comment: @Philipp And this is correct, why do you think it should be a straignt line?

Comment: My aim is plotting a linear regression line to the data, irrespective of the possibility that other non-linear regression lines may better capture the data.

Comment: Linear functions with interceptions don't look straight at log-log plots.

Comment: My aim is to apply a regression line on the log-log freq+data. I do not want to apply the linear regression on the non-logarithmic scale. Is this possible using ```stats.linregress```?

Comment: It's possible. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I tried to achieve.